# Oracle SQL Query Question

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table setup in an oracle database:

```
Column Pk_foo1
Column Pk_foo2
Column Pk_foo3
```

How do I select the rows that are **not unique** if it were the case that Pk_foo1 and Pk_foo2 were the only primary keys.

An example of a select query would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Pk_foo1, Pk_foo2
FROM Table
GROUP BY Pk_foo1, Pk_foo2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```